# How to use controller as service in a yaml resource file

Tags: php, yaml, silex, symfony-components

I'm using **Silex** Framework.
I wrote a simple route resource loader that is used that way :

```
    $app->register( new RouteCollectionLoaderProvider);
    $app["mp.route_loader"]->append(array(
            array(
                    "type"=>"yaml",
                    "path"=>__DIR__."/Resources/routes/routes.yml",
                    "prefix"=>"/",
                )
    ));
```

the source code is here : https://github.com/Mparaiso/silex-extensions/blob/master/src/Mparaiso/Provider/RouteCollectionLoaderProvider.php

i'm able to load routes named the regular way  ,for instance , in a yaml file

```
index:
  pattern: /
  defaults: {_controller: Controller\DefaultController::index }
```

but i'm unable to load controllers defined as services :

```
$app["my.controller"] = function(){ return new MyController;};

info:
  pattern: /info
  defaults: {_controller: my.controller:info }
```

what would it take to be able to use the controller as a service syntax in a resource file ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silex ships with a [ServiceControllerServiceProvider](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/service_controller.html), which you can use to get controllers as services.

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\ServiceControllerServiceProvider());

$app['my.controller'] = $app->share(function ($app) {
    return new MyController($app['my.service']);
});

$app->get('/info', 'my.controller:info');
```

This should work with your custom loader as well.